# LDAP Authentication with Java, explanation needed

Tags: java, authentication, ldap

if you could please explain to me one piece of the following code that I don't quite understand I would be grateful:

What does `(&(cn=*)({0}={1}))` mean in the filter field?

I know that `cn` means search for the `cn` attribute and then ADD the result to `({0}={1})`.

What is the meaning of `({0}={1})`?

Here's  the code:

```
try {
     // Create initial context
     ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
     Attributes matchAttrs = new BasicAttributes(true);
     matchAttrs.put(new BasicAttribute(ldap_id_field, netid));

     String attlist[] = {ldap_email_field, ldap_givenname_field, 
            ldap_surname_field, ldap_phone_field};

    // look up attributes
      try {
      SearchControls ctls = new SearchControls();
     ctls.setReturningAttributes(attlist);
     NamingEnumeration answer = 
     ctx.search(ldap_search_context, "(&(cn=*)({0}={1}))", new Object[]  {ldap_id_field,netid},ctls);
     }
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks wrong to me. All that filter does is find entries which have any CN and which match an attribute name/value pair specified as arguments to the search, in ldap_id_field and netid respectively. There is no 'adding' going on: the & means that both filter-expressions must match.

Comment: Yes, I see you are right. So, if the ldap_id_field is say uid and netid is user123, the search will look for attributes cn=* and will match {0}={1} for uid and user123 (that is, uid=user123). Is this correct?

Comment: I got it now. Thanx. You helped me understand. Accepted you answer